# How to add Custom Content Type Fields to Template in a SharePoint Add-In

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to recreate [this](https://dikuw.wordpress.com/2016/06/01/impress-your-boss-autogenerate-a-word-doc-with-metadata-in-sharepoint-online/) functionality in a SharePoint add-in using Visual Studio 2015. I'm stuck at customizing the MS Word template to include metadata fields (DevNumber, DevOpen, etc). If I create a content type in SharePoint itself, I get a template that includes my fields as custom proprieties. How can I get similar functionality in a SharePoint add-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the app, then create a document using the default template.dotx. Update the document how you want the template to look, including adding property fields, then save the file as template.dotx in the appropriate folder - something like: https://myAppWeb/MyProjects/Lists/MyList/Forms